Name of a certain bipartite graph
Does a graph, obtained from a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ by removing $n$ edges none of which is adjacent to another one of them, have a standard name/notation?

Here are the graphs of this type with: 6 vertices (6-cycle),
8 vertices (cube graph),
10 vertices,
12 vertices,
14 vertices, ... (at least if I understood the definition correctly). It does not appear that they have a name notable enough to make it onto the House of Graphs.

This question used the notation $K_{n,n}-I$.

It is called a crown graph on $2n$ nodes.
